# emailing diff output between two files only if there is a difference

Tags: linux, email, unix, diff

How can I email the output between file1 and file2 but only if there is a difference? Lets say I'm using a shell script.

```
diff file1 file2 | mail -s "subject" "email@email.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the || concatenation.

```
diff -q file1 file2 || diff file1 file2 | mail -s "subject" "email@email.com"
```

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817964/run-two-commands-in-case-of-or)

Comment: that worked. Seems to be a better solution than if then statement. Thank you

Comment: You can also use `cmp` to compare files, which is lighter weight and more portable than `diff -q`.

Comment: did a bit of research but I won't say cmp is faster, source: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153286/is-cmp-faster-than-diff-q

Comment: The summary of the accepted answer there is *"Any difference in performance is pure coincidence. Use whatever you wish."*. I would submit that without a performance difference, the option which is more portable is preferable. And @André, the test that muru published on github is Linux-only, and will not run on systems that use non-GNU tools.

Comment: what do you mean by more portable? couldn't find anything on that

Comment: On non-Linux systems, `diff` may not have a `-q` option ([HP/UX](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=diff&manpath=HP-UX+11.22), [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/diff-1.html#scrolltoc)), or the `-q` option may behave differently from what you expect ([OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/diff)). "Portable" is usually synonymous with "follows standards", in this case POSIX.2. If you write to a standard to which everyone adheres, your code will be portable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this online, it worked great

```
command > file
if [ -s file ]
then
   mailx -s "Subject" mailaddress <file.tmp
fi
rm file
```